# Is it possible to install ROS Indigo on an RPi3 using Ubuntu Mate 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is it possible to install ROS Indigo on an RPi3 using Ubuntu Mate 16.04? If yes then please recommend any tutorial. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285986/is-it-possible-to-install-ros-indigo-on-an-rpi3-using-ubuntu-mate-16.04?/) by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Indigo Igloo is mainly targeted at Ubuntu 14.04. It's probably possible to install it from source on Ubuntu 16.04, but at least on x86-64 (64 bit PC architecture), it was easier to upgrade to ROS Kinetic Kame when upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 than to get the ROS Indigo Igloo packages working.

Is there any reason why you want to use ROS Indigo Igloo? Even if you have to make some changes to your ROS applications, it's probably easier to go for Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic Kame.

---

Originally posted by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) with karma: 206 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-03-25**:
I wanted to use gmapping and other ROS packages for autonomous mapping and navigation. Are they all available on ros kinetic?

**Comment by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) on 2018-03-27**:
I think so. gmapping and rtabmap are, but the only way to know for sure is to check all of them on the ROS website (http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php?package_type=package&distro=kinetic or check the individual packages (on top of the page, you see the distributions including the package)).